# Multiple emails

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, weblogic, quartz-scheduler, weblogic-10.x

We have our application deployed in two different servers(Weblogic). We have functionality to send email as scheduled. Since our application is running in two different servers users are getting 2 emails(Each from one server). We need to restrict it to 1. Ideas are welcome.

Comment: You can use a shared database between the two servers where you can track to whom email is sent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have not described your system fully but still considering generally, there are many solution of this problem

- **Marking send email at central position may be a data store or memory cache**:

  put all scheduled email in a central repository either cache or data store and each email sender application mark the email sent as it sends email, so other application will check any email if it is not already sent by other email sender component
- **Making a separate component for email which get data from both and send scheduled email**:
  one possible solution may be that email sending component should be separated from main application and deployed at a single place and interact with email data store or repository and send scheduled emails.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions :) We are planning to make use of option 1.

Comment: As you are using jee your triggered job could publish a message onto a distributed queue, and then consume that using a message driven bean, ensuring only one node in the cluser consumes and publishes the email

Comment: @user2198540 if you found any of the suggested answers useful, consider to mark it as "correct". Will help foture visitors to spot which one was (for your case) the most helpful. (And also reward the Answerer with reputation points)

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution could be to have a queue and you have a UDQ and an MDB consuming the message and sending the email. This solution will work when one of the 2 managed servers goes down and scales well when you are dealing with many messages.

Using DB could add bottleneck if your load is high.

putting the mail component on only one server could compromise on high availability.

Comment: I have implemented using a logic of name of server. I know the names of servers in which my application will be deployed, hence using INetAddress I got the name of server and in DB I made entries which has to be my email sending server and which should serve as monitoring server(This server will send email once the first server fails). I was able to acheive better solution that what I was actually wanted :).